# Get all INPUT and ACTION tags within a FORM when its SUBMIT button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

We have form tags like below in our HTML pages:

```
<form method= POST action=https://mysite_1.com> 
<input type=hidden name=XXXX value=yyyyyy> 
<input type=hidden name=YYYY value=zzzzz>
<input type=submit name=NNNN value=aaaaa> 
</form>

<form method= POST action=https://mysite_2.com> 
<input type=hidden name=PPPP value=kkkkk> 
<input type=hidden name=MMMM value=lllll>
<input type=submit name=FFFF value=jjjjj> 
</form>
```

There can be multiple such form and action within the HTML page. I need to find all input and action values at form level when a submit action is made?

The problem I am facing is to detect which "submit" button of which "form" and its "action" value at form level in the page?

Comment: Why are u doing this in javascript instead of in php?

Comment: My requirement is in JS script only to capture UI flow level details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a specified form submission-handling function, which can retrieve the attributes from whichever element is being submitted:

```
function submission(form, e){
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    var formAction = form.action,
        formMethod = form.method;
    console.log(formAction, formMethod);
}

var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');

for (var i=0, len=forms.length; i<len; i++){
    forms[i].onsubmit = function(e){
        submission(this, e);
    };
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9a7Ua/).

The above is a slightly-outdated approach, the better alternative uses `addEventListener()` (or `attachEvent` (IE), but without IE to test I can only offer `addEventListener()`:

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');

for (var i=0, len=forms.length; i<len; i++){
    forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        submission(this, e);
    });
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9a7Ua/1/).

Comment: Why would you prevent the default action? (By the way, `preventDefault`  isn't defined in IE<9. You have to return `false`.)

Comment: Only because if the default event is not prevented then the forms would have been submitted during the demo. In real life I'm not sure what JavaScript would have time to *do* before a new page was loaded =/

Answer (score 0):

Assign an id to the forms:

```
<form id="form1" method="POST" action="https://mysite_1.com"> 
...
</form>

<form id="form1" method="POST" action="https://mysite_2.com"> 
...
</form>
```

Then attach an event listener to them to capture the `submit` event:

```
document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit", function() {
    var inputs = this.elements;
    // Do something
}, false);
document.getElementById("form2").addEventListener("submit", function() {
    var inputs = this.elements, action = this.action;
    // Do something
}, false);
```

**Note**: IE<9 needs to use `attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener`:

```
document.getElementById("form1").attachEvent("onsubmit", function() {
    var form = document.getElementById("form1").elements,
        inputs = form.elements, action = form.action;
    // Do something
});
```

And the this keyword refers to the useless `window` object, so you have to use `getElementById` again. You can avoid all this using a common framework library like jQuery or Prototype or Mootools or whatever, or you can define a [good `addEvent` function](http://ejohn.org/projects/flexible-javascript-events/).

Comment: Thanks - is it possible without changing the HTML page. Will I be able to get the form "action" value?